# Remove excess punctuation sign with Regular expressions

Tags: python, pandas, excel, notepad++

Изучаю English. Написал python комбайн. Несколько прог, подчиненных одной цели: сделать красивые ссылочки в excel,с релевантными фразами,которые мне нравятся,примерами использования фраз, ссылочками на удобный сайтик. Такие:[image: excel table]

Собственно три проги:
Код 1:Удаление переноса строк

```
    with open('myfile.txt') as in_file:
        for s in (line.rstrip() for line in in_file.readlines()):
            print(s, end="")
```

Код2:Выбирает только релевантные и нужные фразы из английского текста без стоп слов:

```
import pandas as pd
from rake_nltk import Rake
import re
import stop_words
r = Rake(min_length=2, max_length=10) 
text = "text of mine "
a=r.extract_keywords_from_text(text)
b=r.get_ranked_phrases()
c=r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()
file = [x for x in b if 3<len(x) ]
# from googletrans import Translator
# translator = Translator()
# result = translator.translate(file, dest='ru', src="en")
print(file)
print(type(file))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file)
# df = pd.DataFrame(lst).transpose()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\\.....\\Python_Translator.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 50, format1)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 35, format1)
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
writer.save()
#Транслятор не прикручивал, все время - ошибки. Что-то там про group.
```

На выходе - релевантные английские фразочки в столбце A.

Код 3. Ссылочки на сайт. Сылочки отличаются только знаком +, когда меняются слова. Поэтому возможно сделать так:

```
print('https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/' + 'smart' + '+' + 'ass')
text = ['helping+new+york+city+improve','people+say+mean+things','helping+peter+kafka+get','two+years+ago','three+weeks+ago','next+emotional+stand','life+changed+since','got+five+shows','fun+time+travel','different+president+right','get+along','right+decision','different+expectation','really+interested','pretty+much','obviously+made','never+happened','healthcare+stuff','healthcare+expert','donald+trump']
for i in text:
    print('https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/' + i)
```

Проблема в том, что эти ссылочки мне реально делать только в **notepad++**. Не силен я в Regular expressions. Но там плюсики ставятся везде, получается так:

```
['helping+new+york+city+improve',+'people+say+mean+things',+'helping+peter+kafka+get',+'governor+вђ+”+mayor',+'two+years+ago',+'three+weeks+ago',+'next+emotional+stand',+'life+changed+since',+'got+five+shows',+'fun+time+travel',+'different+president+right',+'вђ+”',+'get+along',+'right+decision',+'different+expectation',+'welcome+back',+'really+interested',+'pretty+much',+'obviously+made',+'never+happened',+'healthcare+stuff',+'healthcare+expert',+'donald+trump']+
```

C помощью: `Find \s+`, `Replace на '+'`.

Потом лишние плюсики приходится ручками удалять. Так себе.

**Вопрос в этом:** *как найти регулярное выражение в python, чтобы добавить плюсы именно между нужными словами, а не где попало.* И вообще, возможно ли объединить три проги в одну? Круто будет.

Comment: Подозреваю, что 80% вопроса можно сократить, оставив только то что к самому вопросу относится..

Comment: Название вопроса должно быть на русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Для замены `' '` на `'+'` в строке, регулярные выражения не нужны, достаточно встроенного строкового метода `str.replace()`:

```
list_of_strings_with_space_delimiter = [ 
                                            'helping new york city improve',
                                            'people say mean things',
                                            'helping peter kafka get',
                                            'two years ago',
                                            'three weeks ago',
                                            'next emotional stand',
                                            'life changed since',
                                            'got five shows',
                                            'fun time travel',
                                            'different president right',
                                            'get along',
                                            'right decision',
                                            'different expectation',
                                            'really interested',
                                            'pretty much',
                                            'obviously made',
                                            'never happened',
                                            'healthcare stuff',
                                            'healthcare expert',
                                            'donald trump'
                                        ]

for string in list_of_strings_with_space_delimiter:
    print(string.replace(' ', '+'))
```

**Результат**

```
helping+new+york+city+improve
people+say+mean+things
helping+peter+kafka+get
two+years+ago
three+weeks+ago
next+emotional+stand
life+changed+since
got+five+shows
fun+time+travel
different+president+right
get+along
right+decision
different+expectation
really+interested
pretty+much
obviously+made
never+happened
healthcare+stuff
healthcare+expert
donald+trump
```

Если изменённые строки должны быть в виде итерируемого объекта, то можно поместить их в новый список:

```
list_of_strings_with_plus_delimeter = [string.replace(' ', '+') for string in list_of_strings_with_space_delimiter]
```

либо использовать генератор (предпочтительнее):

```
generator_of_strings_with_plus_delimeter = (string.replace(' ', '+') for string in list_of_strings_with_space_delimiter)
```